# SqlException was unhandled in C# - Information into Database Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I'm new to coding in C# and have looked around but finding it hard to extrapolate an answer for my problem.

I'm currently just trying to get to grips with adding text and selected text from a combobox into a simple database table. However when I try to add the information I get an error of SqlException was unhandled. I've looked at other answers and saw it maybe something to do with adding a connection, which I've tried but it's still not working...

My code and error message as in the image link below but just in case here is my code also,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SavetoDbTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection test = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\SavetoDbTest\\SavetoDbTest\\Hobbie.mdf;Integrated Security=True")) 
            {
                using (SqlCommand again = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    again.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table Values('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + comboBox1.Text + "')";

                    again.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
                    again.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobby", comboBox1.Text);
                    again.Connection = test;
                    test.Open();
                    again.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    test.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Entry Successful");

                }
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not enclose the contents of button1_Click in a try --- catch block & see what exception has been thrown.

Comment: @PaulF Or throw the exceptions in the debugger by putting a couple of checkmarks in the screen that pops up when you hold control-alt-e in visual studio.

Comment: Also, this is not the standard way of using `connectionstring` Use something like `ConnectionStringSettings mySetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"];`

Comment: you give 2 parameters a value with the AddWithValue statement, but I dont see these parameters in you CommandText.

Comment: @MarcelTheis No, the opposite is true. Instead of removing the parameters, don't write the text directly into the statement!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**+1** for trying to use parameterized queries! But you're not doing it right :-)

```
again.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table Values('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + comboBox1.Text + "')";
again.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
again.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobby", comboBox1.Text);
```

This add parameters when the query string doesn't expect them. Probably this is also the cause for the exception you're seeing.

Your query string must look like this:

```
again.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table] Values(@Name, @Hobby)";
```

Also, `TABLE` is a reserved word in SQL. So if your table is named `Table`, you should wrap it in square brackets.

Comment: Ah yeh I saw that below, didnt realise it was a reserved word! Thanks a lot, hopefully it works now

Comment: I hope so. In addition, Instead of posting a screenshot of the error window, it would be more helpful if you told us what the exception details are. What is the *exact* cause for the error? There should be more information under "View Detail".

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip, I'll remember to use that in the future for including more detai lto help everyone out! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead of:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection test = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\SavetoDbTest\\SavetoDbTest\\Hobbie.mdf;Integrated Security=True")) 
    {
        using (SqlCommand again = new SqlCommand())
        {
            again.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [TableName] Values(@Name,@Hobby)";
            again.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
            again.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobby", comboBox1.Text);
            again.Connection = test;
            test.Open();
            again.ExecuteNonQuery();
            test.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Entry Successful");
         }
    }      
}
```

Comment: Table is a reserved word it should be [Table] if he insists on using this name. But +1 for using parameters correctly

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 issues in your code.
1) you have reserved keyword for table name, Table
2) SQL query you are building from code is incorrect.
3) You need to specify your command type.

Solution: Change table name to something meaningful, like employeedata or testdata and modify your code according to given below.

```
again.CommandType =  CommandType.Text;
again.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestData(ColumnName1,ColumnName2) Values('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + comboBox1.Text + "')";
               again.Connection = test;
                test.Open();
                again.ExecuteNonQuery();
                test.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Entry Successful");
```

Comment: If the table only has two columns, the syntax he uses is perfectly fine. Also, please don't encourage the use of non-parameterized queries.

Comment: Also, you do not have to specify the command type if you're issuing a text command, as this is the default. You only need to change it if you want to call a stored procedure directly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by `PaulF` it is always a good practise to use `Try..Catch` block. It will give you the exception message if the code doesn't works for you. Here you go.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection test = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionStringName"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand again = new SqlCommand())
            {
                again.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table Values(@Name,@Hobby)";
                again.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
                again.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobby", comboBox1.Text);
                again.Connection = test;
                test.Open();
                again.ExecuteNonQuery();
                test.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Entry Successful");

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Check whether it is working or not. Hope atleast it will give you one step ahead result to let you know if any exception arises

Comment: This is the second-most pointless implementation of an exception handler... This will provide no more details than the stacktrace he gets in Visual Studio when the debugger stops showing the exception.

Comment: You mean to say using `try catch` block is useless ? let me know if there is any other better way of doing this.

Comment: No. Throwing the exception in the catch block is pointless. If you only rethrow it, there's no point catching it in the first place. For debugging purposes, this also has not value, because if the exception is not handled, Visual Studio will stop where the exception is thrown displaying an exception window where you can view the stacktrace and other stuff. I'm not saying that handling exceptions is pointless. I'm saying that your code does not handle the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Precisely this exception is being thrown because `table` is a reserved keyword. SQL engine encounters this reserved keyword, when it expects to find a proper name of the table and thus throws an exception. Try specifiying correct table name, because I believe this `table` name was given just as an example.

Your statement should look a little bit more like this 
`INSERT INTO MyTable Values ...`

Other answers about using parametrized query in incorrect way are also valid.

Comment: I didn't realise that Table was a reserved keyword so just kept what the table was named automatically. Thanks for the advice and I'll give it a try